# Poppler failing to install using Macports; no existing solutions seem to work

Tags: macos, macports, poppler

I've been trying to install poppler on my Mac using Macports, as it is a dependency for something else.  I'm having no luck.  I've followed a number of discussions for people with the same problem, but the solutions do not fix the problem. Thank you in advance if you are able to surmise what is wrong here!

**My details:**

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- MacOSX Big Sur (version 11.2.3 (20D91))
- XCode Version 12.4 (12D4e)

**Here is the output when I run port install:**

```
Warning: The macOS 11.2 SDK does not appear to be installed. Ports may not build correctly.
Warning: You can install it as part of the Xcode Command Line Tools package by running `xcode-select --install'.
--->  Computing dependencies for poppler
--->  Fetching archive for poppler
--->  Attempting to fetch poppler-20.12.1_2.darwin_20.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/poppler
--->  Attempting to fetch poppler-20.12.1_2.darwin_20.x86_64.tbz2 from https://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/poppler
--->  Attempting to fetch poppler-20.12.1_2.darwin_20.x86_64.tbz2 from https://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/poppler
--->  Configuring poppler
Error: Failed to configure poppler: configure failure: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
Error: Processing of port poppler failed
```

**I'm unable to update the SDK to get rid of that warning.**

**Here is the log file:**

```
:msg:archivefetch --->  Fetching archive for poppler
:debug:archivefetch Executing org.macports.archivefetch (poppler)
:debug:archivefetch euid/egid changed to: 0/0
:debug:archivefetch chowned /opt/local/var/macports/incoming to macports
:debug:archivefetch euid/egid changed to: 502/501
:info:archivefetch --->  poppler-20.12.1_2.darwin_20.x86_64.tbz2 doesn't seem to exist in /opt/local/var/macports/incoming/verified
:msg:archivefetch --->  Attempting to fetch poppler-20.12.1_2.darwin_20.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/poppler
:debug:archivefetch Fetching archive failed: The requested URL returned error: 404 
:msg:archivefetch --->  Attempting to fetch poppler-20.12.1_2.darwin_20.x86_64.tbz2 from https://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/poppler
:debug:archivefetch Fetching archive failed: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
:msg:archivefetch --->  Attempting to fetch poppler-20.12.1_2.darwin_20.x86_64.tbz2 from https://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/poppler
:debug:archivefetch Fetching archive failed: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (poppler)
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (poppler)
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch Skipping completed org.macports.extract (poppler)
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch Skipping completed org.macports.patch (poppler)
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:configure configure phase started at Mon Apr 26 15:34:12 IST 2021
:notice:configure --->  Configuring poppler
:debug:configure Preferred compilers: clang macports-clang-9.0 macports-clang-11 macports-clang-10
:debug:configure Using compiler 'Xcode Clang'
:debug:configure Executing proc-pre-org.macports.configure-configure-0
:debug:configure Executing proc-pre-org.macports.configure-configure-1
:debug:configure Executing org.macports.configure (poppler)
:debug:configure Environment: 
:debug:configure CC='/usr/bin/clang'
:debug:configure CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES'
:debug:configure CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS'
:debug:configure CFLAGS='-pipe -Os -DNDEBUG -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
:debug:configure CPATH='/opt/local/include'
:debug:configure CPPFLAGS='-isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
:debug:configure CXX='/usr/bin/clang++'
:debug:configure CXXFLAGS='-pipe -Os -DNDEBUG -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
:debug:configure DEVELOPER_DIR='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'
:debug:configure F90FLAGS='-pipe -Os -m64'
:debug:configure FCFLAGS='-pipe -Os -m64'
:debug:configure FFLAGS='-pipe -Os -m64'
:debug:configure INSTALL='/usr/bin/install -c'
:debug:configure LDFLAGS='-Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -liconv -Wl,-syslibroot,/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
:debug:configure LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib'
:debug:configure MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='11.2'
:debug:configure OBJC='/usr/bin/clang'
:debug:configure OBJCFLAGS='-pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
:debug:configure OBJCXX='/usr/bin/clang++'
:debug:configure OBJCXXFLAGS='-pipe -Os -DNDEBUG -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
:debug:configure SDKROOT='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
:info:configure Executing:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/work/build" && /opt/local/bin/cmake -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/opt/local" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_DIR="/opt/local/lib" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/local;/usr" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="$CC" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="$CXX" -DCMAKE_OBJC_COMPILER="$CC" -DCMAKE_OBJCXX_COMPILER="$CXX" -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0025=NEW -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0060=NEW -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/make -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="/opt/local/share/cmake/Modules" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/local/share/cmake/Modules" -DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH="/opt/local/lib" -Wno-dev -DENABLE_UNSTABLE_API_ABI_HEADERS=ON -DENABLE_QT5=OFF -DENABLE_QT6=OFF -DBUILD_GTK_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_QT5_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_QT6_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_CPP_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_NSS3=ON -DUSE_BOOST_HEADERS=OFF --enable-introspection -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="x86_64" -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="11.2" -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk" /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/work/poppler-20.12.1 
:debug:configure system:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/work/build" && /opt/local/bin/cmake -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/opt/local" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_DIR="/opt/local/lib" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/local;/usr" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="$CC" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="$CXX" -DCMAKE_OBJC_COMPILER="$CC" -DCMAKE_OBJCXX_COMPILER="$CXX" -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0025=NEW -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0060=NEW -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/make -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="/opt/local/share/cmake/Modules" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/local/share/cmake/Modules" -DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH="/opt/local/lib" -Wno-dev -DENABLE_UNSTABLE_API_ABI_HEADERS=ON -DENABLE_QT5=OFF -DENABLE_QT6=OFF -DBUILD_GTK_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_QT5_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_QT6_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_CPP_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_NSS3=ON -DUSE_BOOST_HEADERS=OFF --enable-introspection -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="x86_64" -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="11.2" -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk" /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/work/poppler-20.12.1 
:info:configure -- The C compiler identification is unknown
:info:configure -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
:info:configure -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
:info:configure -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
:info:configure -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang
:info:configure -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang - broken
:info:configure CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
:info:configure   The C compiler
:info:configure     "/usr/bin/clang"
:info:configure   is not able to compile a simple test program.
:info:configure   It fails with the following output:
:info:configure     Change Dir: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/work/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
:info:configure     
:info:configure     Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_c0e15/fast && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_c0e15.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_c0e15.dir/build
:info:configure     Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c0e15.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
:info:configure     /usr/bin/clang   -pipe -Os -DNDEBUG -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk  -arch x86_64 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_c0e15.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/work/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
:info:configure     clang: error: invalid version number in 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.2'
:info:configure     make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_c0e15.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1
:info:configure     make: *** [cmTC_c0e15/fast] Error 2
:info:configure     
:info:configure     
:info:configure   
:info:configure   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
:info:configure Call Stack (most recent call first):
:info:configure   CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
:info:configure -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
:info:configure See also "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/work/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
:info:configure See also "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/work/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
:info:configure Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/work/build" && /opt/local/bin/cmake -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/opt/local" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_DIR="/opt/local/lib" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/local;/usr" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="$CC" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="$CXX" -DCMAKE_OBJC_COMPILER="$CC" -DCMAKE_OBJCXX_COMPILER="$CXX" -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0025=NEW -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0060=NEW -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/make -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="/opt/local/share/cmake/Modules" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/local/share/cmake/Modules" -DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH="/opt/local/lib" -Wno-dev -DENABLE_UNSTABLE_API_ABI_HEADERS=ON -DENABLE_QT5=OFF -DENABLE_QT6=OFF -DBUILD_GTK_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_QT5_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_QT6_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_CPP_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_NSS3=ON -DUSE_BOOST_HEADERS=OFF --enable-introspection -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="x86_64" -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="11.2" -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk" /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/work/poppler-20.12.1 
:info:configure Exit code: 1
:error:configure Failed to configure poppler: configure failure: command execution failed
:debug:configure Error code: NONE
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: command execution failed
:debug:configure     while executing
:debug:configure "$procedure $targetname"
:error:configure See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/main.log for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: The macOS 11.2 SDK does not appear to be installed. Ports may not build correctly.

This (believing an SDK version exactly corresponding to the macOS version must exist) was a bug in MacPorts 2.6.4 that was [fixed in 2.7.0](https://github.com/macports/macports-base/blob/v2.7.0/ChangeLog#L9-L10). Run `sudo port selfupdate` to update to the latest version of MacPorts if you haven't already.

> clang: error: invalid version number in 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.2'

Your command line tools are out of date. There is a bug in macOS that prevents them from updating automatically. Update them by [manually downloading](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Command%20Line%20Tools) and installing the version of the CLT that matches your Xcode version, or follow the [instructions on the MacPorts site](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist#reinstall-clt), and do this again anytime Xcode is updated. File a bug report with Apple asking them to fix the macOS bug. The more people who do this, the more likely they are to realize how significant the problem is and fix it.